# Swifter error "AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet." with Django models

Tags: python, django, pandas, swifter

I'm trying to populate a database with django models and I've used the Swifter structure to parallelize a pandas apply, like this:

```
df.swifter.force_parallel(enable=True).apply(lambda row: migrate(row), axis = 1)
```

When apply function loaded 1000 objects into database it gave me "AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet." error.

The function `migrate` is used for each row in dataframe to create the data on db with django models

Answer (score -1):

Seems that swifter (or what's under the hood) processes disrespects the django global context.

The workaround is to invoke `django.setup()` inside of your apply function.

That's fast, but it can mess some things. For example, for me logging doesn't work no more for the usual context.